# outline 1px solid red not working scale hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a PSD like this.

[image: menu]

I want to create like https://www.khaneyeax.com/en/ site, And When I put the mouse on the link, a circle will appear on the link. And I use bootstrap 4.5.

CSS

```
ul.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding: 60px 0 16px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 110px;
}

ul.navbar-nav > li > a > i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    right: 0;
}

ul.navbar-nav > li {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

ul.navbar-nav > li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    outline: solid 1px red;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 35px;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.navbar-nav > li:hover:before {
    transform: scale(30);
    outline-width: 1px;
}
```

a simple Html HTML

```
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-th-large fa-2x"></i>
        <span>Home</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I see this demo.

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hover psuedo class on your button and add a border to the icon on the hover along with a `border-radius` of 50%, this will add the circle around the icon. In my example I use a span tag and image for the ICON: `ul li a:hover span:first-of-type` -->  when we hover over the a tag, we affect the `span:first-of-type` which is the ICON in my example. It will need some tweaking for your CSS, but hopefully you can see how this can be accomplished with CSS psuedo hover.

EDIT: As for animation, add `@keyframes` rule in CSS to the psuedo element. In my example I have added two animations with the same duration. One is for the `a` tag `background-color` and `color`, the other is for the psuedo element `:after` using the 'opacity' setting. Because this is the psuedo `:after` it allows the original image icon to show through without being affected by the opacity setting in the animation.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

ul li a:hover {
  animation: fadebg 0.8s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #800080;
  color: #FFF;
}

@keyframes fadebg {
  from {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #FFF;
  }
  to {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #800080;
  }
}

ul li a span:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

ul li a:hover span:first-of-type:after {
  content: '';
  animation: fadein 0.8s ease-in-out;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1.5px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  align-content: center;
  left: 32px;
  padding: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

li span {
  display: block;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
      <span><img class="icon" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/minimal-set-two/32/minimal-39-128.png"></span>
      <span>Home</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want to create an animition

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi see my edit... Added animation using CSS `@keyframes` rule to the psuedo `:after` selector.